# Split string into chucks at the end of any blank line breaks

Tags: vb.net, split

I want to split a string into separate chunks in VB.Net after each empty line break.

For example if I have the following single string :

```
Jason Smith
Steve
Mary

Harry
Larry
```

I want the first set of names from Jason to Mary in array(0) & the next set in array(1). So the logic should be to split at the empty line break between the 2 sets.

I tried the below code :

```
Dim lines As String() = nameList.Split(New String() {vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

But this just breaks every name into a separate item on the array.

Comment: what is `nameList` here ? is that a single string or an array or reading from file?

Comment: nameList is a single string that is read from a txt file

Comment: I think you would have to use loops or Linq.

Comment: The problem is that all your names are separated by new line, not only Mary and Harry. Do you have the possibility to change the text files content? If so I would change the first delimeter to comma: `"Jason Smith,Steve,Mary" & Environment.NewLine & "Harry,Larry"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split using vbCrLf + vbCrLf to get the different sets. Then split each of those with a single vbCrLf for the values in each array.

Comment: thnks this did the job. I was just going to write a stupid loop. saved a lot of lines of unnecessary code. :)

Comment: here is the final code that I used:

`Dim lines As String() = nameList.Split(New String() {vbCrLf + vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None)`